How should i obtain this layer blur at the borders?
I am creating a custom card in Flutter, and I want the bottom area to have a blur effect with rounded corners. However, I am struggling to achieve the desired look at the borders. Here's the widget I have implemented:
Container(
          height: widget.height.h,
          width: 100.w,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //color: Colors.blue, // You can change this color
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 65.h,
                width: 100.w,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.event.assets.length,
                  onPageChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      pageIndex = value;
                    });
                    if (videoPlayerController != null) {
                      togglePlayPause(isPlay: false);
                    }
                    if (widget.event.assets[value].type ==
                        MediaEnum.video.name) {
                      initPlayer = true;
                      initVideoPlayer(
                        videoUrl: widget.event.assets[value].url,
                        isAutoPlay: true,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          child: widget.event.assets[index].type ==
                                  MediaEnum.video.name
                              ? _buildVideoContent(index)
                              : _buildImageContent(index),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    // Shadow container
                    Container(
                      height: 11.5.h, //   12.h,//110,
                      width: 96.w,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                            blurRadius: 10, // Increase blur for more fade
                            spreadRadius: 10, // Increase spread for wider fade
                            offset: Offset(0, -1), // Center the shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Main content with blur
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: BackdropFilter(
                        blendMode: BlendMode.src,
                        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 11.5.h, //110
                          width: 100.w,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.w),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              colors: [
                                Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.1),
                                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
                                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.15),
                                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                              ],
                              stops: [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0],
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 1.5.h,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 89.w,
                                    child: Text(
                                      widget.event.name,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 19.5.sp,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        color: colorScheme.background,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text(
                                StringExtension.formatDateForNewEventCard(
                                    widget.event.startDate),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.sp,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  color:
                                      colorScheme.background.withOpacity(0.8),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Row(children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "${widget.event.priceRangeStart.toIndianRupeeString()}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: colorScheme.background,
                                        fontSize: 16.sp,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 55.w,
                                      child: Text(
                                        " onwards, (${widget.event.coverChargeEnabled ? 'Cover Charge Applicable' : 'Free'})",
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15.5.sp,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          color: colorScheme.background
                                              .withOpacity(0.8),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                  if (widget.isInListing)
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.h),
                                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                          AssetConstants.longArrowRight,
                                          width: 30,
                                        ))
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 110,
                right: 10,
                child: widget.event.assets[pageIndex].type ==
                            MediaEnum.video.name &&
                        isPlaying
                    ? ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: widget.isMutedNotifier,
                        builder: (context, isMuted, child) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (widget.isInListing) {
                                toggleMuteUnmuteForValueListener(isMute);
                              } else {
                                //  print("is mute ${isMute}");
                                toggleMuteUnmute();
                              }
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              height: 12.5.h,
                              width: 12.5.h,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: [
                                  SvgPicture.asset(
                                    widget.isInListing
                                        ? (isMuted
                                            ? AssetConstants.muteFillIcon
                                            : AssetConstants.unmuteFillIcon)
                                        : (isMute
                                            ? AssetConstants.muteFillIcon
                                            : AssetConstants.unmuteFillIcon),
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        })
                    : SizedBox(
                        width: 4.5.w,
                        height: 3.h,
                      ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 100,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  //  height: 4.h,

                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 1.5.h,
                      right: widget.isInListing ? 1.8.h : 0,
                      bottom: 2.h),
                  width: 95.w,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      //play pause button
                      widget.isInListing
                          ? SizedBox()
                          : widget.event.assets[pageIndex].type ==
                                      MediaEnum.video.name &&
                                  widget.isInListing
                              ? GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print("is playingMain ${isPlaying}");
                                    togglePlayPause(isPlay: !isPlaying);
                                  },
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 3.5.w,
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          Theme.of(context).colorScheme.shadow,
                                      child: Icon(
                                        isPlaying
                                            ? Icons.pause_rounded
                                            : Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 4.5.w,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : SizedBox(
                                  width: 4.5.w,
                                  height: 3.h,
                                ),

                      //page indicator
                      widget.event.assets.length <= 1
                          ? const SizedBox()
                          : Center(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  ...List.generate(
                                      widget.event.assets.length,
                                      (dotIndex) => Padding(
                                            padding: dotIndex ==
                                                    widget.event.assets.length -
                                                        1
                                                ? EdgeInsets.zero
                                                : EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.0.w),
                                            child: Container(
                                              height: 1.9.w,
                                              width: 1.9.w,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                  color: pageIndex == dotIndex
                                                      ? Theme.of(context)
                                                          .colorScheme
                                                          .background
                                                      : Theme.of(context)
                                                          .colorScheme
                                                          .secondaryContainer),
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),

                      // mute button
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (widget.isInListing)
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 105.w,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        if (widget.event.pub != null)
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 3.w, vertical: 2.h),
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 80.w,
                                    child: Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            AnalyticsService().logEvent(
                                                eventName: 'view_club',
                                                paras: {
                                                  'club_id': widget
                                                      .event.pub!.id
                                                      .toString(),
                                                });

                                            navigator<NavigationService>()
                                                .navigateTo(
                                                    UserRoutes.clubProfileRoute,
                                                    queryParams: {
                                                  'id': widget.event.pub!.id
                                                      .toString()
                                                });
                                          },
                                          child: CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 4.5.w,
                                            backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                CustomImageProvider.getImageUrl(
                                                    widget.event.pub?.logo ??
                                                        "",
                                                    // widget.event.pub?.coverImageUrl ?? '',
                                                    ImageType.profile)),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 2.w,
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              navigator<NavigationService>()
                                                  .navigateTo(
                                                      UserRoutes
                                                          .clubProfileRoute,
                                                      queryParams: {
                                                    'id': widget.event.pub!.id
                                                        .toString()
                                                  });
                                            },
                                            child: Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                              children: [
                                                GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    AnalyticsService().logEvent(
                                                        eventName: 'view_club',
                                                        paras: {
                                                          'club_id': widget
                                                              .event.pub!.id
                                                              .toString(),
                                                        });
                                                    navigator<
                                                            NavigationService>()
                                                        .navigateTo(
                                                            UserRoutes
                                                                .clubProfileRoute,
                                                            queryParams: {
                                                          'id': widget
                                                              .event.pub!.id
                                                              .toString()
                                                        });
                                                  },
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    widget.event.pub!.fullName,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    maxLines: 1,
                                                    style: themeData
                                                        .textTheme.bodyMedium!
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                            color: themeData
                                                                .colorScheme
                                                                .background,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight.w600,
                                                            fontSize: 16.5.sp),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Text(
                                                  widget.event.address
                                                          ?.vicinity ??
                                                      '',
                                                  maxLines: 1,
                                                  overflow:
                                                      TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  style: themeData
                                                      .textTheme.bodySmall!
                                                      .copyWith(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                                                    color: themeData
                                                        .colorScheme.background,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ],
          ),
        )

the result i got:

the desired result i want :

What I tried:
Used BackdropFilter with ClipRRect to apply the blur effect.
Added a gradient and shadow to enhance the appearance.

  List<Widget> buildBlurImage(List<Widget> l) {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    list.addAll(l);
    double sigmaX = 0;
    double sigmaY = 0.1;
    double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75;
    for (int i = deviceHeight.toInt(); i < 700; i += 3) {
      // deviceHeight.toInt() is the starting height of blur
      // 700 is the ending height of blur
      list.add(Positioned(
        top: i.toDouble(),
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: ClipRect(
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: sigmaX,
              sigmaY: sigmaY,
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
      sigmaX += 0.1;
      sigmaY += 0.1;
    }
    return list;
  }

Use method as below
    Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: buildBlurImage([
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/028/718/011/non_2x/exquisite-victorian-christmas-tree-adorned-with-festive-antique-ornaments-exuding-an-aura-of-classic-elegance-and-tradition-photo.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 55.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Greetings...",
                    style: TextStyle(shadows: <Shadow>[
                      Shadow(
                        offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                        blurRadius: 3.0,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                      ),
                    ], fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Merry Christmas",
                    style: TextStyle(shadows: <Shadow>[
                      Shadow(
                        offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                        blurRadius: 3.0,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                      ),
                    ], fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ],
      ),


this is not giving that blur feel

In Stack try to give 1st child --
Positioned.fill(
child: BackdropFilter(
filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
child: Container(
color: Colors.transparent,
),
),
),

still not working

I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.
